# How is it possible to supply Integer to setter expecting double?

Tags: java

I have this snippet:

```
class scratch_5{
  public static void main(String theory[]){
    Item i = new Item();
    Integer a = 3;
    i.setNum(a);
    System.out.println(i.getNum());
  }

}

class Item{
   double num;

   public void setNum(double num){this.num=num;}
   public double getNum(){return num;}
}
```

Can you explain to me how is this possible? I understand that double wrapper class is Double, and both Integer and Double are derived from Number, hence they shouldn't be possible to use interchangeably

Comment: Any integer can be represented by a double so it's not surprising that it works. The opposite is not true though you can still explicitly cast a double to an integer (you will, of course, lose precision)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It compiles because `Integer` is unboxed to an `int`, which is then safely widened to `double`.

According to [Section 5.1.2 of the JLS: *Widening primitive conversions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>   ...
>   `int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`
>   ...
>   Despite the fact that loss of precision may occur [in some conversions], a widening primitive conversion never results in a run-time exception

---

What you *couldn't* do is the opposite:

```
class Item {
    public void setNum(Double num) {...}
}

int a = 3;
i.setNum(a);   // compile error
```

Java won't widen *and* autobox.

Comment: ah, ok, didnt know about this casting, or is it not casting officially ?

Comment: @Medardas See edited answer for relevant links to the JLS